# How to efficiently add multi index data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to accumulate counts of number of people who fit particular criteria in specific areas and dates.

So, as an example, setting up a dataframe of the correct final shape with 0 counts might look like this:

```
dfmi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2],[1,2],[0,1,2],[0]],names=['AREA','DATE','GROUP','COUNTS'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = dfmi).reset_index()
df.set_index(['AREA','DATE','GROUP'],inplace=True)

Out[52]: 
                 COUNTS
AREA DATE GROUP        
1    1    0           0
          1           0
          2           0
     2    0           0
          1           0
          2           0
2    1    0           0
          1           0
          2           0
     2    0           0
          1           0
          2           0
```

...where I have reduced the number of areas and the number of dates to 2 for the ease of showing what I'm after.

To generate the counts I am iterating over a data frame 'PEOPLE' and determining on which dates each row (person) belongs to each group, then adding a data frame that looks like the above example (except that all counts are 1 and only specific dates, areas, and groups are present).  After I go through all of the rows, I have the cumulative counts.  I have a line that looks like:

```
total_counts = total_counts.add(df,fill_value=0)
```

This process is already slow because I am calculating a number of things to determine which group they should belong to over what range of dates.  I noticed that it is much slower as the total_counts data frame grows larger.  I thought perhaps it was an issue with having to reallocate memory as total_counts grew, but beginning with an empty data frame that has the correct shape and 0s everywhere (as in the above example) does not help at all.

I am trying to do this for ~10^7 rows.  I am rethinking my approach with respect to generating the data frames of counts each time, but I am also curious if there is a faster way to deal with the addition of data frames.

Any thoughts and insights would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have all of AREA, DATE and GROUP in the PEOPLE dataframe, then simply grouping by these columns should give you what you want - e.g. `PEOPLE.groupby['AREA', 'DATE', 'GROUP'].size()`.

Comment: @Lynn Thanks but I do not - I am calculating which dates elsewhere and then adding counts based on the calculation.  That is why I am doing it this way (which is not to say there isn't a better way to do it).